# Копирование внутри массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем привет!
Помогите решить задачу плиз

Есть массив let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}];

Необходимо дозаполнять массив элементами с начала списка пока длина массива не станет 20

Всем спасибо за помощь.

---

По сути необходимо дублировать объекты пока длина массива не станет 20

Comment: Возможно, есть смысл в создании поверхностных копий обьектов. `const fillToSize = (arr, length) => Array.from({length}, (_, i) => ({...arr[i % arr.length]}));
` (пишу с телефона, функцию не проверял)

Answer (score 4):

let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}];

`arr[0]` — это ссылка на объект. Если в каком-нибудь цикле начать дублировать по `arr[i]`, будут копироваться именно ссылки, а не сами объекты (из-за чего теряется весь смысл такого действия). А создание новых объектов с такими же свойствами и значениями, можно организовать так:

```js
let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}];

arr = new Array(20).fill(0).map(
  (e,i) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( arr[ i % arr.length ] ))
);

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 3):

Универсально.

**ES6**

```
let count = 20;
let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}, {id:3, name: 'Item3'}];
let fill = Array(...new Array(count)).map((_, i) => arr[i % arr.length]);
console.log(fill);
```

**ES5**

```
var count = 20;
var arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}, {id:3, name: 'Item3'}];
var fill = Array.apply(null, new Array(count)).map(function(_, i) { return arr[i % arr.length] });
console.log(fill);
```

Обновил как предложил @optimus-prime

Comment: `i - arr.length * Math.floor(i / arr.length)` → `i % arr.length`

Comment: да, перемудрил. спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы еще вот так попробовал)

```
let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}];
let res = [];
while (res.length < 20){
    res.push(...arr);
}
```

А вот для зацикливания

```
  let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}];
let res = [];

while (res.length != 20){
        for(let a of arr){
      if(res.length < 20) { 
         res.push(a); 
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Через for и 2 счетчика:

```
let arr = [{id:1, name: 'Item1'}, {id:2, name: 'Item2'}, {id:3, name: 'Item3'}];
let arrs = [];
var m = 0
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    if(typeof arr[m]!="undefined"){
        arrs[i] = arr[m];
        m++;
    } else {
        m=0;
        i--;
    }
}
arr = arrs; // console.log(arr)
```

Comment: В arr может быть не только два объекта. Там может быть и один и три и пять. Суть в том чтобы дозаполнять до 20 массив элементами с начала списка.

Comment: Stas Verevkin, исправил решение, проверяй. Работает с любым числом объектов